# Connect GIATA hotel mapping with postman

Tags: laravel, api, postman

I am trying to use GIATA multi-codes for hotels mapping but they have HTTP Basic authentification when i type url like this https://multicodes.giatamedia.com/webservice/rest/1.0/properties/country/US  pop up appears to write my username and password but how to work with that using api request with postman for example

I tried adding username:password@url but still doesn't work with me

Answer (score 0):

In each tab to make a request, you have an "Authorization" tab. Normally, a page protected by an .htpasswd is only a basic authentication.

Have you tried in the "Authorization" tab to choose the type "Basic Auth" and put your username and password in it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a username as follows:

The user name for authentication consists of the name of the user (usually the first part of the email address before "@") + | (Pipe) + the company name.

Thus access is granted using:

User name

```
testUser|testCompany
```

Password

```
testPw
```

For example: user|company.com